# Send message to Facebook into a secret group (not on user's wall)

Tags: serviceexecute

Does someone know if Mathematica 10 allows to send messages to Facebook but not on the user's wall rather to a secret or closed group?
I have an small application that reads some data from a web site each 10 minutes and I would automatically post an updated image of such data on a secret group on Facebook.
Thanks in advance,
Roberto

Comment: Is there any other API you know of to do this?

Comment: @Igor Rivin No, I just used SendMessage, for instance: SendMessage["Facebook", "I sent this message from the Wolfram Language."] and it works, but the message is sent to my account's wall. I need to send it to a private group. Now, I'll search if any API is available on the net. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook graph API lets you do this (obviously):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/group/feed

which means that you can take any of the external wrappers for it ([python](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) would be my favorite), and just run it as an external command.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I thought it was an internal option of SendMessage or other Mathematica built-in similar function. However, I'll take a look at that API. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I get the answer from the Technical Support at Wolfram, they confirmed that currently there is not a native command or option to send messages to facebook groups, but it could be in the next releases.

Comment: @bobknight I am quite sure that using the python wrapper for Facebook native functionality will be a LOT more robust (since WRI cannot get their .csv support straightened out after about, oh, 20 years, I would imagine that must faster moving targets like the FB interface is not going to be better.